# DataBinding, DataSet, DataAdapter e DataGridView: Para que servem, como usar e em que ordem?

Tags: c#, .net

Estou tentando aprender a usar o controle DataGridView já fazem semanas (sim, semanas).

Fazer a conexão com o banco usando o designer é muito fácil, mas quero fazer por código e não consigo.

Vi alguns tutoriais na web, porém embora seguir um passo a passo pronto seja fácil, não consegui entender como tudo funciona, de forma que eu conseguisse a fazer o processo da maneira que eu bem entender.

Pelo que entendi a propriedade `DataSource` do `DataGridView` deve receber um `DataSet`, que por sua vez me parece ter alguma relação com `DataAdapters` , mas não consigo entender nada disso. A documentação da Microsoft ao invés de ajudar me deixou ainda mais confuso.

Gostaria de saber então as seguintes coisas:

1. Para que serve cada um dos itens citados.
2. Como usá-los para me conectar ao banco sem usar o designer.
3. Em que sequência devo usá-los para conseguir recuperar informações do banco através do controle `DataGridView`.

Comment: Estou achando esta pergunta muito ampla.

Comment: Pensei que isso pudesse acontecer. O que recomenda que eu faça, visto que são vários problemas em um.

Comment: Separe o máximo possível. É melhor fazer 30 perguntas que dê resposta de um parágrafo do que um pergunta que gere 30 parágrafos. São muitas  classes, perguntando várias coisas, e pedindo o que no fundo é um tutorial completo. Dividir e conquistar é o segredo. Vai num passo de cada vez. Tem várias vantagens nisso. No fim vc obtém tudo o que precisa, ajuda outras pessoas e tudo organizado. E ganha + rep :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Vou responder suas perguntas em ordem.

> Para que serve cada um dos itens citados.

## Data Binding

Este é o único que não é um componente, e sim um conceito. Ele enuncia como componentes de dados se ligam uns aos outros.

O que pode causar alguma confusão é que o componente [`DataGridView`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview(v=vs.110).aspx) possui uma propriedade chamada [`DataBindings`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.control.databindings(v=vs.110).aspx) (no plural mesmo), esta sim usada para descrever como interpretar uma origem de dados (veja mais abaixo).

## [`DataSet`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.data.dataset(v=vs.90).aspx)

É um conjunto de dados estruturado em memória de aplicativo. Ele pode ter vindo de um banco de dados, de um arquivo de texto, de uma planilha Excel, etc., o que chamamos genericamente de "origem de dados" (*Data Source*, em inglês).

A classe `DataSet` no .NET normalmente representa um conjunto de [uma ou mais tabelas de uma origem de dados](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.data.datatable(v=vs.90).aspx).

Aqui começa alguma confusão. Esta origem de dados que falamos aqui não é exatamente a mesma coisa que a origem de dados de componentes visuais, por exemplo (como a propriedade [`DataSource`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.datasource(v=vs.110).aspx) de [`DataGridView`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview(v=vs.110).aspx)). Ela pode ser 4 coisas:

1. Um objeto que implementa [`IList`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.collections.ilist(v=vs.110).aspx);
2. Um objeto que implementa [`IListSource`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.componentmodel.ilistsource(v=vs.110).aspx) (aqui sim entram `DataTable` e `DataSet`);
3. Um objeto que implementa [`IBindingList`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.componentmodel.ibindinglist(v=vs.110).aspx);
4. Um objeto que implementa [`IBindingListView`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.componentmodel.ibindinglistview(v=vs.110).aspx).

Os mais usados são os dois primeiros. Essa quantidade de opções pode confundir um pouco, e procuro explicar isso mais abaixo.

## [`DataGridView`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview(v=vs.110).aspx)

O nome já explica um pouco. É uma visão em grade de dados.

Sendo uma visão de uma grade de dados, o componente só pode detalhar uma estrutura de lista de cada vez. Ou seja, se você ligar um `DataSet` inteiro ao componente, terá que indicar a ele qual estrutura irá utilizar.

Se o objeto ligado implementar `IList`, apenas a seguinte construção é suficiente para ligar a origem de dados ao `DataGridView`. Procure usar também [`AutoGenerateColumns`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.autogeneratecolumns(v=vs.110).aspx) para criar as colunas de acordo com a formatação do objeto da lista:

```
List<MeuObjeto> meusObjetos = new List<MeuObjeto> { new MeuObjeto { Nome = "Cigano" } };
dataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
dataGridView.DataSource = meusObjetos;
```

Se o objeto é do tipo `DataSet`, será preciso ainda informar as propriedades [`DataMember`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.datamember(v=vs.110).aspx) e [`AutoGenerateColumns`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.autogeneratecolumns(v=vs.110).aspx) para o `DataGridView`:

```
DataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
DataGridView.DataSource = ds; // dataset obtido antes.
DataGridView.DataMember = "MeusObjetos";
```

## E [`DataBindings`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.control.databindings(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Bom, esta é a maneira complicada de configurar a `DataGridView`, até porque `DataBindings` se aplica a qualquer objeto `Control`, então estaríamos falando, na verdade, de ligar coluna a coluna com cada elemento da origem de dados. [Os exemplos de uso do `DataBindings` mais comuns são com componentes mais simples, como o `TextBox` e o `DateTimePicker`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.control.databindings(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2), e os exemplos com `DataGridView` são tão difíceis de achar que não vale a pena colocar exemplos de uso na resposta, até porque os métodos acima contemplam bem a ligação entre componente de grade e origem de dados.

> Como usá-los para me conectar ao banco sem usar o designer.

Programaticamente falando, pode ser como abaixo. Note que aqui uso um `DataAdapter` pela primeira vez, cuja função é preencher o objeto em memória com o resultado do banco de dados:

```
string connString = "Data Source=SeuBanco; Initial Catalog=.\SQLEXPRESS; User Id=usuario; Password=senha";
string sql = "SELECT * FROM Tabela";

SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);

con.Open();
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataTable registros = new DataTable();
da.Fill(registros);

dataGridView.DataSource = registros;
```

> Em que sequência devo usá-los para conseguir recuperar informações do banco através do controle DataGridView.

A ordem normalmente é a mesma:

1. Trazer os dados na origem de dados, seja ela uma `List`, `DataTable` ou `DataSet`;
2. Ligar à `DataGridView` usando a propriedade [`DataSource`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.datasource(v=vs.110).aspx) juntamente com as orientações acima.